# Dynamically place legend in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating plots in pyplot in Python. Each plot contains two or more subplots. I know I can statically place a legend in the plot by defining the parameter `loc`; however, my choice of location will sometimes cover the data in my plot. How would I place the legend dynamically in the location that interferes with the data the least?

Comment: does the `loc=0` ('best') setting not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tcaswell has already stated, use `ax.legend(loc='best')`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
pi = np.pi
sin = np.sin
t = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * pi, 50)
markers = ['+', '*', ',', ] + [r'$\lambda$']
phases = [0, 0.5]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(phases))
for axnum, phase in enumerate(phases):
    for i, marker in enumerate(markers, 1):
        ax[axnum].plot(t, i*sin(2*t + phase*pi), marker=marker,
                   label='$i,\phi = {i},{p}$'.format(i=i, p=phase))
    ax[axnum].legend(loc='best', numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Interestingly, the location of the legend is not fixed. If you
move the graph using the GUI, the location of the legend will readjust itself automatically.